# Installing 200amp service in my old house

Tags: electrical

New 200amp meter box from Consumers Energy to a GE 200amp 240V transfer switch box to my 200amp Sq. D Homeline breaker box. Do I bring my new ground cable into my breaker box and do I use the bonding screw in the breaker box or in the transfer switch box?

Comment: Do you know how your generator is wired specifically the grounding.

Comment: There are two types of transfer switches. One is rated as a service entrance capable and the other is not allowed to be before the main disconnect. Is your transfer switch service rated?

Comment: What's your rationale for whole-house transfer here?  And yes, is your transfer switch *service entrance* rated?